# How to force inheritance of the properties included from external file in OrgMode

Tags: org-mode, org-properties

#### Problem - introduction

Let's say we've got the following org file

```
* Headline 1 with name taken from properties - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")}
:PROPERTIES:
:Name:  J.S. Bach
:END:

** SubHeadline
```

During the export "J.S. Bach" is included in Headline 1 according to my expectation. Since properties are not inherited by default we cannot add
`src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")}` in the subheadline.

But we can turn the properties inheritance on, and then it is possible
to export the following piece of code (Do observe the usage of
`'selective` flag - without it the example wouldn't work!):

```
# -*- mode: Org; org-use-property-inheritance: t -*- 
* Headline 1 with name taken from properties - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")}
:PROPERTIES:
:Name:  J.S. Bach
:END:

** SubHeadline  - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name" 'selective)}
```

#### Problem - question

Now I would like to keep properties in a different file. Let's call the
file "properties.txt" and let it have the following content:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:Name:  Newman
:END:
```

*Is it possible to make these properties being inherited like in the example
above?*

1. Approach 1 - failure

   This doesn't work:

   ```
   # -*- mode: Org; org-use-property-inheritance: t -*- 
   * Headline 1 with name taken from properties - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")}
   #+INCLUDE: ./properties.txt

   ** SubHeadline  - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name" 'selective)}
   ```

   I get "Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil" error.
2. Approach 2

   This does work but it's less convenient:

   ```
   # -*- mode: Org; org-use-property-inheritance: t -*- 
   * Headline 1 with name taken from properties - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")}
   #+INCLUDE: ./properties.txt

   ** SubHeadline  - src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name" 'selective)}
   #+INCLUDE: ./properties.txt
   ```

Comment: `Approach 1` works fine for me. Org mode version: 9.7-pre (release_9.6.7-678-gcc435c). What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: My org-mode version is 9.6.1. I played a bit with "Approach 1" and found out that it works indeed but only if  the subheadline has some content (it could be  subsubheadline or whitespace like =\quad or \nbsp{}). Approach 1 in the form presented above or with added spaces or new lines or even with added second subheadline (headline of level two) below the first SubHeadline, results in the error message.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, run it again and post the backtrace.

Comment: Backtrace:: https://pastebin.com/PaYZCA4x

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a rather obscure bug in `org-babel-where-is-src-block-result`. I can still reproduce it in 9.6.12, but not in upstream. The bug fix is *probably* [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=9fd547dd3a16c473b2109bfd7bad7f1cb015a5b2). Unfortunately, it depends on some other commits as well, so it cannot be applied on its own. You are either going to have to upgrade to the main branch, or wait until the next release or request that it be backported to the bugfix release (but given the dependencies I mentioned, that might be difficult).

Comment: Fortunately, I can circumvent this bug. In my particular use case I can assume that a node always needs to have some content. Thank you.