# How to access node property in my own export process

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-properties

Given an org document, I'd like to traverse all headlines of the
given level and extract the headline title, provided that:

1. Headline title can be generated by inline source blocks that use node properties, and
2. I don't know beforehand what are the names of the node properties that are going to be used to generate the headline.

For example for the document given below:

```
* Section about src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")} :this:
:PROPERTIES:
:Name:     J.S. Bach
:END:

* Section about src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Composer")} :this:
:PROPERTIES:
:Composer:     W.A. Mozart
:END:

* Code
#+begin_src elisp :eval yes :results output :exports both

(defun level1-headlines-filter ()
  (setq headline (org-entry-get nil "ITEM"))
  (setq props (org-get-entry))
  (setq string (concat headline "\n" props))
  (setq string (org-export-string-as string 'org t '(:with-toc nil)))
  (setq all (list string)))

(setq HEADLINES-PARSED (org-map-entries #'level1-headlines-filter "LEVEL=1+this") )

(print HEADLINES-PARSED)

#+end_src
```

`HEADLINES-PARSED` should contain strings:

```
"Section about J.S. Bach"
"Section about W.A. Mozart"
```

Now the results are:

```
(("Section about 
:PROPERTIES:
:Name:     J.S. Bach
:END:
") ("Section about 
:PROPERTIES:
:Composer:     W.A. Mozart
:END:
"))
```

Comment: `org-export-string-as` copies the given string to a temp buffer and runs `org-export-as` on that buffer. You give it only the headline as the string to copy, so it is missing the `PROPERTIES` drawer and the source block evaluation does not find *any* property and returns an empty string. You have to at least copy the `PROPERTIES` drawer as part of the string that you want to export, not just the headline.

Comment: @NickD Basing on your comment I have rewritten the code a bit. I moved forward a bit, the output changed but it is still not the result I expect to obtain. Could you provide some more help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out, the headline by itself is not enough for `org-export-string-as` to work: it is missing the context of the PROPERTIES drawer, so trying to evaluate source blocks that look for properties in the temp buffer that `org-export-string-as` constructs is not going to work.

In addition, the headline is no longer a headline: it has lost the initial `*`  that made it into a headline. So that has to be added back to the string, before `org-export-string-as` can have any hope of working.

Somewhat surprisingly, that seems to be enough, at least for the simple example you provide. The function `level1-headlines-filter` can and should be simplified: there is no need for all the variables, although I've kept a couple of local variables for readability's sake below. The following seems to work:

```el
(defun level1-headlines-filter ()
  (let (headline props)
    (setq headline (org-entry-get nil "ITEM"))
    (setq props (org-get-entry))
    (org-export-string-as (concat "* " headline "\n" props) 'org t '(:with-toc nil))))
```

I get:

```
#+RESULTS:
:results:

("* Section about =J.S. Bach=
" "* Section about =W.A. Mozart=
")
:end:
```

BTW, the verbatim markup in this result seems to be a bug, but it has not been resolved yet AFAIK. The [commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=9fd547dd3a16c473b2109bfd7bad7f1cb015a5b2) that I pointed out as fixing the bug (in the upstream main branch only alas) you ran into in your [previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79480/how-to-force-inheritance-of-the-properties-included-from-external-file-in-orgmod) points to a [conversation on the mailing list](https://orgmode.org/list/CA+G3_PNt7WqkCzChV+dx1FeSPgTEVkNSE41a3qC5wv3g+jTwrQ@mail.gmail.com) where this point is discussed as another bug (see [further down the thread](https://list.orgmode.org/orgmode/CA+G3_POs_Dq=DGqLyEHP2uTfrHfYk0inDKsRSYy2SGBi4ZvJtg@mail.gmail.com/)): a workaround is shown, but no final resolution is reached.

Comment: Thank you Nick! The verbatim markup is indeed a problem in my case. Fortunately I have circumvented it by removing unnecessary characters from the output strings [(see my answer)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/79510/30035). Rather brute force approach but it works in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on NickD's helpful comments I have come up with the solution that satisfies my personal needs in this case. The code:

```
* Section about src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Name")} :this:
:PROPERTIES:
:Name:     J.S. Bach
:END:

* Section about src_elisp{(org-entry-get nil "Composer")} :this:
:PROPERTIES:
:Composer:     W.A. Mozart
:END:

* Code
#+begin_src elisp :eval yes :results output :exports both

(defun replace-in-string (what with in)
  (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote what) with in nil 'literal))


(defun level1-headlines-filter ()
  (let (headline props)
    (setq headline (org-entry-get nil "ITEM"))
    (setq props (org-get-entry))
    (setq string 
          (replace-in-string "\n" "" 
          (replace-in-string "* " "" 
          (replace-in-string "=" "" 
          (org-export-string-as 
            (concat "* " headline "\n" props) 
            'org t '(:with-toc nil))))))
   ))

(setq HEADLINES-PARSED (org-map-entries #'level1-headlines-filter "LEVEL=1+this") )

(print HEADLINES-PARSED)

#+end_src
```

generates expected:

```
#+RESULTS:
: 
: (("Section about J.S. Bach") ("Section about W.A. Mozart"))
```

Comment: I would get rid of the `(setq string` (and the corresponding closing paren): the function works by returning the string, so you don't need to store it.

Comment: Well... after a while spent on thinking about it, it is possible rewrite the function in such a way that there is no need to use `setq` at all. Those `setq`s are just artifacts from my programming in non-functional languages. They help me to understand what is going on between all those billions of parenthesis ;)